# how to call url link from onchange in select dropdown

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates

Normally i am calling from GET button with url '/filterSelectedStatus/'

```
<input type = "submit" value = "  Get  " align="center" onclick="javascript: form.action='/filterSelectedStatus/';"/>
```

But samething i need call from onchange in django templates.But below code not working...

```
<select name = "selStatus" onchange = '/filterSelectedStatus/' method = 'get' >
    {% for list in statusList %}
        <option value = "{{ list}}"> {{ list }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
    <option selected= "{{ selStatus }}">{{ selStatus }} </option>
</select>
```

Thanks,
Ramesh.

Answer (score 0):

The `onchange` attribute is used to call javascript, as documented [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp). In your javascript, create a function like:

```
var filterSelectedStatus = function (e) {
    // Log the event e to the console to see what you can do with it
    console.log(e);
    // Do whatever you want here, like JavaScript GET requests
};
```

Then simply change your html to

```
<select name = "selStatus" onchange = 'filterSelectedStatus()'>
    {% for list in statusList %}
        <option value = "{{ list}}"> {{ list }} </option>
    {% endfor %}
    <option selected= "{{ selStatus }}">{{ selStatus }} </option>
</select>
```